# Scikit learn/pandas - predict text(present in xlsx) on user input using machine learning

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have Xlsx file with predefined text with one column only. User will enter word or words and output will be text containing word or words.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
import re
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer, CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import linear_kernel, cosine_similarity
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances
import pickle


def load_df(path):
    df = pd.read_excel(path)
    print(df.shape)
    return df


def splitDataFrameList(df, target_column, separator):
    def splitListToRows(row, row_accumulator, target_column, separator):
        split_row = row[target_column].split(separator)
        for s in split_row:
            new_row = row.to_dict()
            new_row[target_column] = s
            row_accumulator.append(new_row)

    new_rows = []
    df.apply(splitListToRows, axis=1, args=(new_rows, target_column, separator))
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_rows)
    return new_df


class Autocompleter:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def import_json(self, json_filename):
        print("load Excel file...")
        df = load_df(json_filename)
        return df

    def process_data(self, new_df):

        # print("select representative threads...")
        # new_df = new_df[new_df.IsFromCustomer == False]

        print("split sentenses on punctuation...")
        for sep in ['. ', ', ', '? ', '! ', '; ']:
            new_df = splitDataFrameList(new_df, 'UserSays', sep)

        print("UserSays Cleaning using simple regex...")
        new_df['UserSays'] = new_df['UserSays'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x.split()))
        new_df['UserSays'] = new_df['UserSays'].apply(lambda x: x.strip("."))
        new_df['UserSays'] = new_df['UserSays'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x.split()))
        new_df['UserSays'] = new_df['UserSays'].apply(lambda x: x.strip("-"))
        new_df['UserSays'] = new_df['UserSays'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x.split()))
        # new_df['UserSays'] = new_df['UserSays'].apply(lambda x: x.lower())
        new_df['UserSays'] = new_df['UserSays'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(' i ', ' I '))
        new_df['UserSays'] = new_df['UserSays'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(' ?', '?'))
        new_df['UserSays'] = new_df['UserSays'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(' !', '!'))
        new_df['UserSays'] = new_df['UserSays'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(' .', '.'))
        # new_df['UserSays'] = new_df['UserSays'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('OK', 'Ok'))
        # new_df['UserSays'] = new_df['UserSays'].apply(lambda x: x[0].upper() + x[1:])
        new_df['UserSays'] = new_df['UserSays'].apply(lambda x: x + "?" if re.search(r'^(Wh|How).+([^?])$', x) else x)
        new_df['UserSays'] = new_df['UserSays'].apply(lambda x: x.capitalize())

        print("calculate nb words of sentenses...")
        new_df['nb_words'] = new_df['UserSays'].apply(lambda x: len(str(x).split(' ')))
        new_df = new_df[new_df['nb_words'] > 2]

        print("count occurence of sentenses...")
        new_df['Counts'] = new_df.groupby(['UserSays'])['UserSays'].transform('count')

        print("remove duplicates (keep last)...")
        new_df = new_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['UserSays'], keep='last')

        new_df = new_df.reset_index(drop=True)
        print(new_df.shape)

        return new_df

    def calc_matrice(self, df):
        # define tfidf parameter in order to count/vectorize the description vector and then normalize it.
        model_tf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1, 3), min_df=0)
        tfidf_matrice = model_tf.fit_transform(df['UserSays'])
        pickle.dump(model_tf, open("model.pkl", 'wb'))
        pickle.dump(tfidf_matrice, open("train.pkl", 'wb'))
        print("tfidf_matrice ", tfidf_matrice.shape)
        return model_tf, tfidf_matrice

    def generate_completions(self, prefix_string, data, model_tf, tfidf_matrice):

        prefix_string = str(prefix_string)
        new_df = data.reset_index(drop=True)
        weights = new_df['Counts'].apply(lambda x: 1 + np.log1p(x)).values

        # tranform the string using the tfidf model
        tfidf_matrice_spelling = model_tf.transform([prefix_string])
        # calculate cosine_matrix
        cosine_similarite = cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrice, tfidf_matrice_spelling)

        # sort by order of similarity from 1 to 0:
        similarity_scores = list(enumerate(cosine_similarite))
        similarity_scores = sorted(similarity_scores, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
        similarity_scores = similarity_scores[0:10]

        similarity_scores = [i for i in similarity_scores]
        similarity_indices = [i[0] for i in similarity_scores]

        # add weight to the potential results that had high frequency in orig data
        for i in range(len(similarity_scores)):
            similarity_scores[i][1][0] = similarity_scores[i][1][0] * weights[similarity_indices][i]

        similarity_scores = sorted(similarity_scores, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
        similarity_scores = similarity_scores[0:]
        similarity_indices_w = [i[0] for i in similarity_scores]
        final_result = new_df.loc[similarity_indices_w]['UserSays'].tolist()
        return final_result
```

in input if i enter nothing it provides me this output

```
['How to access outlook on open network?', 'Email access outside ril network', 'Log in outlook away from office']
```

which is not desired
and if only one text matched it gives follwing output

```
input - sccm
['What is sccm', 'How to access outlook on open network?', 'Email access outside ril network']
```

I want output in such way that if entered word or words are not present in xlsx file then output should not return me anything.
and

Comment: Looks like you want to apply some sort of threshold on the similarity scores before returning the output.  Right now you're returning values with cosine similarity = 0

Comment: @kev8484 yes correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is returning values with similarity score of 0, I think.  You can change the line in your `generate_completions` function to only keep values with similarity score greater than zero:

```
similarity_scores = [i for i in similarity_scores if i[1] > 0]
```

Comment: i am getting bellow error after changing code
`
    similarity_scores = [i for i in similarity_scores if i > 0]

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'`
`

Comment: i am getting desired output till some point. But for few input its giving blank output.
but thanks for your suggestions